"Unable to read keypair file" during 'anchor test', but ~/.config/solana/id.json is there
I have a project that fails with Unable to read keypair file when I run anchor test:
 anchor test
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.09s

Found a 'test' script in the Anchor.toml. Running it as a test suite!

Running test suite: "/Users/mikemaccana/Code/solana/anchor-movie-review-program/Anchor.toml"

Error: Unable to read keypair file

The error doesn't include the name of the keypair file it is looking for but I have seen this issue before when ~/.config/solana/id.json doesn't exist.
However:

~/.config/solana/id.json does exist
All other projects on my system work. I can make the error occur on demand for other projects by renaming ~/.config/solana/id.json, so it's very clear that other projects are using ~/.config/solana/id.json, just not this one.

I did try and use strace to see the name of the file it's accessing, but strace and dtrace are hard to use on a mac without disabling System Integrity Protection.

Answering my own question to help others:
The wallet is determined by the provider.wallet setting in Anchor.toml. In the case of this program, the git repo had the macOS username of the program's creator in it's Anchor.toml:

[provider]
cluster = "Localnet"
wallet = "/Users/someone-else/.config/solana/id.json"


wallet must be included (there is no default value), but you can make a project use the current user's wallet using ~/.config/solana/id.json.
